# What is a good solution to link different tables in Hibernate based on some field value?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have `article` table and several user tables `a_user`, `b_user`, ... with exactly the same structure (but different data). I can't change anything in `*_user` tables except their table name prefix but can change everything else (user tables contain only user information, there is nothing about article or user_type in them).

I need to link article to a user (many-to-one), but user table name is defined by user_type field. For example

```
Article table record:
...
user_id="5"
user_type="a"
```

means that it is linked to a user with id=5 from `a_user` table (id 5 is not unique in users scope, each user table can have its id 5).

Any suggestions how to handle this situation? How can I map this relation in Hibernate (xml mapping, no annotations) so it will automatically pick up correct user for an article during select/update? How should I map user tables (one or multiple classes?)?

I would need to run some queries like this:

```
from Article a where a.userType=:type and a.user.name=:name
```

Thanks.

Comment: Quite strange database design, how is the foreign key defined for table article?

Comment: Well, currently it is not defined. It used to be a simple many-to-one relation with one user table. Now it has to be several user tables. Why there are several user tables - they are coming from another product (forum), and we have several forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate has `@Any` annotation (and `<any>` xml element) for such designs.

Sorry for annotations, but I'm not good in `hbm.xml`. It can be translated into XML, see [`<any>` element](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping):

```
@Entity @Table(name = "Article")
public class Article {

    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "user_type"))
    @AnyMetaDef(
            idType = "integer",
            metaType = "string",
            metaValues = {
                    @MetaValue(value = "A", targetEntity = UserA.class),
                    @MetaValue(value = "B", targetEntity = UserB.class)
            }
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

`UserA` and `UserB` shares the same schema defined by `User`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    ...
}

@Entity @Table(name = "a_user")
public class UserA extends User {}

@Entity @Table(name = "b_user")
public class UserB extends User {}
```